# Group x-axis in bins with ggplot's geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following ggplot figure, produced by this code:

```
ggplot(PATpols, aes(Period, value, color=IUCN)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = IUCN)) +
  facet_grid(tag ~., scales = "free_y", labeller=label_wrap_gen(width=15)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks= seq(1940, 2015, by=10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  scale_color_viridis(discrete=T) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(size = 8, colour = "black", angle = 0))
```

[image: by_year_figure]

For better visualisation of the trends, I would like to group the x-axis (time) in bins of, say, 10 years. I discovered these days the characteristic of ggplot to group in bins automatically, and I think that it is awesome and very practical for data visualization.

Today, I also learnt that it can be used within geom_line, with `stat = "bin", binwidth = 10`, what could do something like what I need. However, bins work counting, and, in this case, I have the 2 different "y" variables that had been already calculated. The values of each 10 years would have to be summed from the column named "value" in my tidy tibble. 
Trying to use `stat = "bin", binwidth = 10` brings an error saying that it does not work because the "y" variable shouldn't be provided.

```
Error: stat_bin() must not be used with a y aesthetic.
```

Using this code, I was able to get the following figure, obviously wrong because ggplot is counting the number of rows instead of the values.

```
ggplot(PATpols, aes(Period, color=IUCN)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = IUCN), stat = "bin", binwidth = 10) +
  facet_grid(tag ~., scales = "free_y", labeller=label_wrap_gen(width=15)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks= seq(1940, 2015, by=10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  scale_color_viridis(discrete=T) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(size = 8, colour = "black", angle = 0))
```

[image: wrong_10_year_figure]

At this point, I doubt whether it is possible to do this within ggplot or not. Probably not... and it is not that difficult to group data myself.

Nonetheless, I wanted to ask just in case I am missing something.
Thanks for the help!

This is a subset of the table:

```
PATpols <- structure(list(Period = c(1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 
1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 
1980, 1980, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010), variable = c("new.PA", 
"new.PA", "new.PA", "new.PA", "new.PA", "new.PA", "new.PA", "new.PA", 
"new.PA", "new.PA", "new.PA", "new.PA", "new.PA", "new.PA", "new.PA", 
"new.PA", "new.PA", "new.PA", "new.PA", "new.PA", "new.PA", "new.PA", 
"new.PA", "new.PA", "new.area", "new.area", "new.area", "new.area", 
"new.area", "new.area", "new.area", "new.area", "new.area", "new.area", 
"new.area", "new.area", "new.area", "new.area", "new.area", "new.area", 
"new.area", "new.area", "new.area", "new.area", "new.area", "new.area", 
"new.area", "new.area"), value = c(0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 17, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 5575.58852902375, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19008.4210385919, 0, 0, 0, 0, 616.617197104555, 
0, 232.522843017563, 0, 3351.82112023738, 234.321752235977, 0, 
0, 42.7373095251387, 42.7094617704834, 6383.74665457854), tag = c("n", 
"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", 
"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "km2", "km2", 
"km2", "km2", "km2", "km2", "km2", "km2", "km2", "km2", "km2", 
"km2", "km2", "km2", "km2", "km2", "km2", "km2", "km2", "km2", 
"km2", "km2", "km2", "km2"), IUCN = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("I", 
"II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI"), class = "factor")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -48L), .Names = c("Period", 
"variable", "value", "tag", "IUCN"))
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible data for a better solution. You can use ```dput(PATpols)```.

Comment: You can also cut `x` into bins beforehand and then use `stat_summary` to plot a line.

Comment: @A Gore, thanks for your comments. I added the dput object (I didn't do it before because it is quite long). stat_summary sounds like what I could use... but it is first time I hear about it and, so far, I haven't been able to make it work as I need...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the question thanks to the hint provided by @A Gore.

It can be done using "summary_bin" as `stat` parameter inside "geom_line". This code produces the output I was pursuing, here choosing a bin of width 10:

```
ggplot(PATpols, aes(Period, value, color=IUCN)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = IUCN), stat = "summary_bin", binwidth = 10) +
  facet_grid(tag ~., scales = "free_y", labeller=label_wrap_gen(width=15)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks= seq(1940, 2015, by=10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  scale_color_viridis(discrete=T) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(size = 8, colour = "black", angle = 0))
```

[image: right_figure]

Thanks for the help!